# bash && operator prevents backgrounding over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, background-process

After trying to figure out why a Capistrano task (which tried to start a daemon in the background) was hanging, I discovered that using `&&` in bash over ssh prevents a subsequent program from running in the background. I tried it on bash 4.1.5 and 4.2.20.

The following will hang (i.e. wait for `sleep` to finish) in bash:

```
ssh localhost "cd /tmp && nohup sleep 10 >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

The following won't:

```
ssh localhost "cd /tmp ; nohup sleep 10 >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Neither will this:

```
cd /tmp && nohup sleep 10 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Both zsh and dash will execute it in the background in all cases, regardless of `&&` and ssh. Is this normal/expected behavior for bash, or a bug?

Comment: I don't precisely know the answer to your question, but will say that I have occasionally encountered similar irritations when using SSH, with Bash on the remote end.  I do not know if the problem is Bash-specific, but I have sometimes had better luck using the Bash shell's `disown` builtin rather than the `nohup` command.  If this interests you, then type `help disown | less` while running Bash.  And if you happen to learn of a general solution, please do post it here.  I should be interested to read.

Comment: I actually tried mucking about with various combinations of `disown`, `nohup` and redirections, to no avail. The `&&` always inhibited backgrounding. I could get away with wrapping the two commands in a subshell, but that isn't really the same thing.

Comment: The command seems to work for me. What do you mean by hangs? Does the `cd` take a long time? It could be an issue with the remote server, e.g. too much load.

Comment: I do not know what the OP means by "hangs" but, in my case, an attempt to log out never completes.  That is my experience, anyway.  Don't know why.

Comment: By "hangs", I mean that it actually waits for the `sleep` to finish before returning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy solution is to use:

```
ssh localhost "(cd /tmp && nohup sleep 10) >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

(this also works if you use braces, see second example below).

I did not experiment further but I am reasonably convinced it has to do with open file descriptors hanging around.  Perhaps zsh and dash bind the `&&` so that this means what has to be spelled as:

```
{ cd /tmp && nohup sleep 10; } >/dev/null 2>&1
```

in bash.

---

Nope, quick experiment in dash shows that `echo foo && echo bar >file` only redirects the latter.  Still, it has to have something to do with lingering open fd's causing ssh to wait for more output; I've run into this a lot in the past.

---

One more trick, not needed if you use the parentheses or braces for this particular case but might be useful in a more general context, where the set of commands to do with `&&` are more complex.  Since bash seems to be hanging on to the file descriptor inappropriately with `&&` but not with `;`, you can turn `a && b && c` into `a || exit 1; b || exit 1; c`.  This works with the test case:

```
ssh localhost "true || exit 1; echo going on; nohup sleep 10 >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Replace `true` with `false` and the echo of "going on" is omitted.

(You can also `set -e`, although sometimes that is a bigger hammer than desired.)

Comment: Yeah, replacing `&&` with `|| exit 1;` is definitely the workaround to use.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
ssh localhost "(exec 0>&- ; exec 1>&-; exec 2>&-; cd /tmp; sleep 20&)"
```

Comment: The drawback to closing all the descriptors up front is that you can't emit error messages back to the originating (`ssh`) host.